# How to create indexpaths for all rows and all sections for uitableview?

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, nsindexpath

I have a table with n sections. Each section contains one row. How to create the index path for the table? 
There is a method that allows to create index path for all visible rows `[self.tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows]` I need something similar like `indexPathsForAllRows`

I need all this to update only the data in the table, because method `[self.tableView reloadData];` updates all the table with headers and footers. That's why i have to use `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths`

Comment: Why do you need to update off-screen rows? They will get updated in cellForRowAtIndexPath: as long as your model is updated

Comment: You mean that they will be updated as long as they become visible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't need reload *all* the rows. You only need to reload the visible cells (that is why `indexPathsForVisibleRows` exists).

The cells that are off-screen will get their new data in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` once they become visible.

Comment: I've never thought of using indexPathForVisibleRows in this way.

Answer (score 5):

Here is the solution in Swift 3

```
func getAllIndexPaths() -> [IndexPath] {
    var indexPaths: [IndexPath] = []

    // Assuming that tableView is your self.tableView defined somewhere
    for i in 0..<tableView.numberOfSections {
        for j in 0..<tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: i) {
            indexPaths.append(IndexPath(row: j, section: i))
        }
    }
    return indexPaths
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I made a `UITableView` extension based on @Vakas answer. Also the sections and rows have to be checked for `> 0` to prevent crashes for empty `UITableView`s:

```
extension UITableView{
    func getAllIndexes() -> [NSIndexPath] {
        var indices = [NSIndexPath]()
        let sections = self.numberOfSections
        if sections > 0{
            for s in 0...sections - 1 {
                let rows = self.numberOfRowsInSection(s)
                if rows > 0{
                    for r in 0...rows - 1{
                        let index = NSIndexPath(forRow: r, inSection: s)
                        indices.append(index)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return indices
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This code will give you complete indices:

```
extension UITableView {
    func allIndexes() -> [IndexPath] {
        var allIndexes: [IndexPath] = [IndexPath]()

        let sections = self.sectionCount() ?? 0
        if sections > 1 {
            for section in 0...sections-1 {
                let rows = self.rowCount(section: section) ?? 0
                if rows > 1 {
                    for row in 0...rows-1 {
                        let index = IndexPath(row: row, section: section)
                        allIndexes.append(index)
                    }
                } else if rows == 1 {
                    let index = IndexPath(row: 0, section: section)
                    allIndexes.append(index)
                }
            }
        } else if sections == 1 {
            let rows = self.rowCount(section: 0) ?? 0
            if rows > 1 {
                for row in 0...rows-1 {
                    let index = IndexPath(row: row, section: 0)
                    allIndexes.append(index)
                }
            } else if rows == 1 {
                let index = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
                allIndexes.append(index)
            }
        }
        return allIndexes
    }
}
```